# Explicit template specialization of member functions

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following minimal example:

```
class A
{
  template<typename X, typename Y>
  void f()
  { }

  template<>
  void f<int, char>()
  { }
};
```

The compiler gives an error message

```
 explicit specialzation in non-namespace scope.
```

Why is this wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: That means, the specialization should be outside the class.

Comment: Move the specialization outside `A`'s definition.

Answer (score 1):

§14.7.3 [temp.expl.spec]/p2:

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in a namespace enclosing the specialized template.

So you need to move the specialization outside `A`'s definition:

```
class A
{
  template<typename X, typename Y>
  void f()
  { }
};

template<>
void A::f<int, char>()
{ }
```

Answer (score 0):

From the C++ standards:

> An explicit specialization shall be declared in the namespace of which
>   the template is a member, or, for member templates, in the namespace
>   of which the enclosing class or enclosing class template is a member.
>   An explicit specialization of a member function, member class or
>   static data member of a class template shall be declared in the
>   namespace of which the class template is a member.

So you need to move the specialization outside  the scope of A's definition. You may try this:

```
class A
{
  template<typename X, typename Y>
  void f()
  { }
};
template<>
void A::f<int, char>()
{ }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, the paragraph you are quoting has been completely rewritten in C++11.

Comment: @T.C.:- Yes correct. I quoted it from C++03